# New Orleans to Flagstaff (Arizona) - which route is more scenic

Tags: usa, routes, texas, scenic-routes

We'll be visiting USA in summer this year (first time). I'm in the middle of planning our trip. We'll be in New Orleans for two days and then we'll be heading to Grand Canyon. Google maps suggests those two routes:

[image: Google Maps - New Orleans to Flagstaff]

First one goes through Dallas, Wichita Falls and Amarillo (Cadillac Ranch). Second one goes through Abilene and Lubbock. We would like to spend one day in Fort Worth.
Right now I'm considering those two routes but maybe you have better suggestions (not only the highways). We have about 4-5 days to get from New Orleans to Flagstaff.

Are there other routes I should consider?

**More details**
I'll be travelling with my wife. I'm looking for:

- route with small towns along the way, where we could stop for coffee/dinner and see how life is going in Texas
- route where we'll be able to stop and take some landscape pictures (that's why I asked about "scenic")

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Please review the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq) because as the question stands it would be considered very subjective and thus not constructive.  You should edit it providing what you would like to see.

Comment: I think this question is reasonable, although a bit more detail on what the OP would like to see would be helpful. Nevertheless, they've given a specific time period and origin and destination, plus they asked for more "scenic", which whilst always subjective, should be easy to have an opinion on for anyone familiar with the area.

Comment: If this question is "subjective" it probably falls under the heading of "good subjective," because the OP has given us a "binary" choice of only two routes. Answers aren't going to "run away."

Comment: @TomAu The original question(before the edit) lacked details to provide an answer.  North West Texas is basically a lot of flat space used for agriculture.  I'm not much for that kind of scenery but I'm not the one doing the traveling.

Answer (score 5):

Personally once you get past Dallas/Fort Worth area the scenery will consist of a whole lot of nothing.  So if you're looking to take in West Texas life your choices are:

- [Wichita falls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wichita_Falls,_Texas) - [Amarillo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amarillo,_Texas)

or

- [Abilene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abilene,_Texas) - [Lubbock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lubbock,_Texas)

To me the choice is equally dreary though the Abiline - Lubbock Route using US-84 is likely to provide easier access to little towns that will provide more of "Texas" flavor to your journey.

P.S.  If you're looking for pictures of landscape in Texas I'd recommend looking at Google Maps Street View to give you an idea of what you're likely to see.

P.P.S.  You'll miss the oddity in [Sweetwater](http://rattlesnakeroundup.net/) that one might want to see.